# C++ code to upload text file into a file geodatabase on ArcGIS

Tags: c++, text, gdb, arcgis

I'm a C++ beginner but experienced with ArcGIS (used for geodatabases) Here's some code I wrote to upload a text file into a file geodatabase...yes I know the declarations and many things look insane but I am on a deadline and don't know how else to do it (and just don't have the knowledge). Please let me know if you have any input! It would be hugely appreciated.

The issues:
-textFile is not uploading to the gdb
-it's stuck in an endless loop (at least for uploading the text file to the backup text file)
-it's print crazy things to the backup text file that are NOT in the text file.
-probably other things that I have no idea about.
-I posted here because I'm not sure what kind of response it will get on the GIS forum (much more python centered). If you think it will get good advice there...lmk.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   ifstream textFile;
   ofstream backupFile;
   ofstream gdb;
   string RECORDID;
   string SURVEY_TYPE;
   string CLIENT;
   string CERTIFIED_TO;
   string KEYWORDS;
   string SECTION;
   string TOWNSHIP;
   string RANGE;
   string GRANT;
   string SUBDIVISION;
   string PROPERTY_NOTES;
   string PROPERTY_FOLDER;
   string PROJECT_DWG;
   string FEMA_FIRMETTE;
   string LOT_GRADE;
   string FEMA_ELEVATION;
   string JOB_SHEET;
   string FIELD_NOTES;
   string ENGINEER_FOLDER;
   string ADDRESS;
   string CITY;
   string STATE;
   string ZIPCODE;
   string COUNTY;
   string INTERSECT_STREET;
   string ADDITIONAL_NOTES;
   double LATITUDE;
   double LONGITUDE;
   string HTML;
   string DATE_FIELD_WORK;
   string JOB_NUMBER;
   string SEC_TWN_RNG;
   string PROJECT_PDF;
   string LOT;
   string USER;
   string BLOCK;
   string TRACT;
   string DMS_LAT;
   string DMS_LONG;
   string PLAT_BOOK;
   string PLAT_PGS;
   string UNIT;
   string PHASE;
   string HSE;
   string OWNER;
   string SUBDIVISION_PLAT;
   string CTY_FFE_CERT;
   string JOB_NUM_ID;
   string DATE_ADDED;


   cout << "Textfile uploading" << endl;
   textFile.open("test2.txt");
   backupFile.open("backup2.txt");
   gdb.open("test.gdb\\project");

   textFile >> RECORDID >> SURVEY_TYPE >> CLIENT >> CERTIFIED_TO >> KEYWORDS >> SECTION >> TOWNSHIP >> RANGE >> GRANT >> SUBDIVISION >> PROPERTY_NOTES >> PROPERTY_FOLDER >> PROJECT_DWG >> FEMA_FIRMETTE >> LOT_GRADE >> FEMA_ELEVATION >> JOB_SHEET >> FIELD_NOTES >> ENGINEER_FOLDER >> ADDRESS >> CITY >> STATE >> ZIPCODE >> COUNTY >> INTERSECT_STREET >> ADDITIONAL_NOTES >> LATITUDE >> LONGITUDE >> HTML >> DATE_FIELD_WORK >> JOB_NUMBER >> SEC_TWN_RNG >> PROJECT_PDF >> LOT >> USER >> BLOCK >> TRACT >> DMS_LAT >> DMS_LONG >> PLAT_BOOK >> PLAT_PGS >> UNIT >> PHASE >> HSE >> OWNER >> SUBDIVISION_PLAT >> CTY_FFE_CERT >> JOB_NUM_ID >> DATE_ADDED;

   while(!(textFile.eof()))
   {
       gdb << RECORDID << SURVEY_TYPE << CLIENT << CERTIFIED_TO << KEYWORDS << SECTION << TOWNSHIP << RANGE << GRANT << SUBDIVISION << PROPERTY_NOTES << PROPERTY_FOLDER << PROJECT_DWG << FEMA_FIRMETTE << LOT_GRADE << FEMA_ELEVATION << JOB_SHEET << FIELD_NOTES << ENGINEER_FOLDER << ADDRESS << CITY << STATE << ZIPCODE << COUNTY << INTERSECT_STREET << ADDITIONAL_NOTES << LATITUDE << LONGITUDE << HTML << DATE_FIELD_WORK << JOB_NUMBER << SEC_TWN_RNG << PROJECT_PDF << LOT << USER << BLOCK << TRACT << DMS_LAT << DMS_LONG << PLAT_BOOK << PLAT_PGS << UNIT << PHASE << HSE << OWNER << SUBDIVISION_PLAT << CTY_FFE_CERT << JOB_NUM_ID << DATE_ADDED << endl;
       backupFile << RECORDID << " " << SURVEY_TYPE << " " << CLIENT << " " << CERTIFIED_TO << " " << KEYWORDS << " " << SECTION << " " << TOWNSHIP << " " << RANGE << " " << GRANT << " " << SUBDIVISION << " " << PROPERTY_NOTES << " " << PROPERTY_FOLDER << " " << PROJECT_DWG << " " << FEMA_FIRMETTE << " " << LOT_GRADE << " " << FEMA_ELEVATION << " " << JOB_SHEET << " " << FIELD_NOTES << " " << ENGINEER_FOLDER << " " << ADDRESS << " " << CITY << " " << STATE << " " << ZIPCODE << " " << COUNTY << " " << INTERSECT_STREET << " " << ADDITIONAL_NOTES << " " << LATITUDE << " " << LONGITUDE << " " << HTML << " " << DATE_FIELD_WORK <<  " " << JOB_NUMBER << " " << SEC_TWN_RNG << " " << PROJECT_PDF << " " << LOT << " " << USER << " " << BLOCK << " " << TRACT << " " << DMS_LAT << " " << DMS_LONG << " " << PLAT_BOOK << " " << PLAT_PGS << " " << UNIT << " " << PHASE << " " << HSE << " " << OWNER << " " << SUBDIVISION_PLAT << " " << CTY_FFE_CERT << " " << JOB_NUM_ID << " " << DATE_ADDED << " " << endl;
       cout << "Text file was uploaded." << endl;
   }

   textFile.close();
   backupFile.close();
   gdb.close();

system ("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

ANY advice appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try calling `gdb.flush()` once you're done writing?

Comment: no but I will now. where should this go?

Comment: After you're done writing to `gdb`. Also, if you're stuck in an endless loop that means you're never getting to the end of textFile, which makes sense as you never do anything with that in your loop.

Comment: got it. added a count. just having a few issues with some funny field values. will post final code when done. thank you!

Comment: No problem! I'll post it as answer

Comment: ok, still not writing to GDB and getting this strange text on my backup file in the middle of the line (and then nothing else prints):  4.48739e-306 4.48739e-306. it's supposed to be a folder name with spaces (but other spaces print in the backup file so not sure if that's the issue)

Comment: Is test.gdb\\project just a regular text file? I'm not familiar with Geodatabases. Your code looks fine, other than style issues and your loop condition not making any sense. The writing should be working so long as you aren't trying to write into some database using `ostream`.

Comment: I fixed the loop, just haven't posted it because I'm probably going to tweak it some more. What is the correct method for writing into a database?

Comment: You'll need to consult your database's documentation. They should provide some sort of API for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ostream::flush()` to write the data from the stream to the file.

```
while(!(textFile.eof()))
{
    gdb << "All your values...";
}

gdb.flush();
//Close your streams
```

Calling `fstream::close()` on `gdb` like you are doing *should* write any pending data out to the file. I'm not sure why that's not happening for you, but calling `ostream::flush()` will also do it.